# Heroku throws error on plotly dash deployment

Tags: python, heroku, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to deploy a plotly dash to heroku.

I'm new to Heroku, and i'm deploying straight through github, although i've tried the cri, and it didn't make much difference. The source is here:
https://github.com/emmettgb/Quake-Predictor

Dependencies seem to be fine, this is the only output I get when starting it:

```
2019-09-28T02:44:04.858473+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=quake-predictor.herokuapp.com request_id=570b0141-474b-46bd-8d3f-06137d470fce fwd="192.30.199.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-09-28T02:44:05.024444+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=quake-predictor.herokuapp.com request_id=646001dc-c8d2-4fa1-b95b-06432f1a4a55 fwd="192.30.199.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-09-28T02:47:25.786556+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=quake-predictor.herokuapp.com request_id=b26bdb99-9116-44af-a9ad-9445125dae23 fwd="192.30.199.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-09-28T02:47:25.980431+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=quake-predictor.herokuapp.com request_id=9734e9e9-73b9-4ca4-94e0-5ec9c3cb52a8 fwd="192.30.199.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Dependencies seem to be in good shape, so I would love to hear your suggestions. It seems to be having issues accessing it's file system?

Comment: Is your requirements file properly instantiated?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @YaakovBressler . Turns out this is entirely an issue with running Gunicorn with Plotly Dash because of how the assets are setup (and intertwined with Plotly.) To make a long story short, I was able to get it deployed on NGINX by running a different Gunicorn command by socketing the port. So lesson learned -- Plotly Dash and Heroku don't like eachother.

Comment: dang! Glad you got it figured out